# SQL Join that only returns records that are missing in other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider two tables in a SQL Server database:

**Order**

```
OrderId | OrderType | etc...
```

**Shipment**

```
ShipmentId | OrderId | ShipType | etc..
```

I'm trying to write a select statement that returns `OrderId`s :

```
where Order.OrderType = 'EXCHANGE'
```

and there is no corresponding record in the `Shipment` table that has

```
Shipment.OrderId = Order.OrderId and Shipment.ShipType = 'BOX'
```

The reason for this is that depending on the `OrderType`, a BOX may or may not to be shipped to the customer. I want to grab all the OrderIds that are of `OrderType = 'EXCHANGE'` but have no corresponding BOX shipment so they can be forwarded to be shipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from order o
where o.OrderType = 'EXCHANGE' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from shipment s
                  where s.OrderId = o.OrderId and s.ShipType = 'BOX'
                 );
```

Note:  As written this won't work because `order` is a SQL keyword and reserved word -- that makes it a very poor choice of table name (you can escape the name, although you do not in the question).  I would suggest you call it something else, such as `orders`.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a JOIN solution, but a subquery looks like it'll do the trick. Thanks for the tip on the table name too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    o.*
FROM Order o
    LEFT JOIN Shipment s ON s.OrderId = o.OrderId AND s.ShipType = 'BOX'
WHERE
    o.OrderType = 'EXCHANGE'
    AND s.ShipmentId IS NULL
```